# How to access my on-chain BTC private key(s) from my Lightning Node?

Tags: lightning-network

I deposited some BTC to fund my lightning node. Question: Where are the private keys for the public on-chain address provided by the node in case I need to withdraw the funds from the node?

Comment: What software/platform are you using for your Lightning node (and if applicable, for your on-chain wallet)?

Comment: I am using bitcoind with lnd. I used `lncli create` to create the lightning wallet.  I also use ZAP desktop wallet to display the bitcoin address to which I deposited funds.

Comment: With a small research on the lightning network implementation I found that the node has some method to extract it. I'm not in the right moment to implement a answer but fot lnd you can flow the comment under this PR https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/pull/2373